# How to avoid shading of connection bars in TikZ mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, shading, mindmaps

I am trying very hard since a while to draw a mindmap where shading of connection bars is **avoided** and where the connection bar's color is specified by me.

For instance, I would like to draw two green concepts connected by a red connection bar.

This has many applications, typically when the bar's color represents an option (e.g. a red bar meaning true and a green bar meaning false).

Evidently, there is alway the dirty option consisting in manually naming nodes and connecting them manually but this is not viable for large mindmaps. I would just want to specify each connection bar's color and avoid the shading.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, I am precisely trying to produce an example and not managing to... I am not facing a mistake but something that I do not manage to produce.

Answer (score 3):

Not as straightforward as I'd originally thought (unless I've overlooked something), but below I've defined a `connection bar color` key to do the job (which I suppose should strictly speaking be called `circle connection bar color`).

Note that connection bars are drawn on very slightly on top of nodes to avoid gaps caused by TeX math inaccuracies, so the `outer sep` has to set for the concept nodes to take this into account (e.g., `0.5pt` seems to get it roughly on the edges). I've set it so there is a gap as I actually think it looks quite nice in this case.

Also the connection bar color is inherited by any child nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    connection bar color/.style={
        every circle connection bar/.append style={
            append after command={[fill=#1]}
        }
    },
    connection false/.style={
        connection bar color=red!30!purple,
    },
    connection true/.style={
        connection bar color=green!40!orange
    },  
}

\tikz[mindmap, concept color=yellow!50!orange, 
    every concept/.style={
        text=black,
        font=\sf,
        outer sep=1.5pt% Have to determine by trial and error
    },
    level 1 concept/.append style={
        level distance=5cm
    },
    level 2 concept/.append style={
        level distance=4cm
    }
]
\node [concept] {Like cheese?}
    child [grow=30, connection true] { 
        node [concept] {Whiskers?}
            child [grow=30] {% NB connection true inherited
                node [concept] {Mouse}
            }
            child [grow=-30, connection false] {
                node  [concept] {Human}
            }
    }
    child [grow=-30, connection false] {
        node  [concept] {Cat}
    };

\end{document}
```

[image]